# LightningChart JS - Logarithmic axis

Tags: javascript, charts, lightningchart

I would like to show some line series on a logarithmic scale, using LightningChart. I saw that the .NET version has some config options, but I couldn't find any for the JS version.

Is there a way to modify the axis config to show the ticks and data on a logarithmic scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LightningChart JS has now Logarithmic axes, and there's several examples how to use them in [LightningChart JS interactive examples](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/)

Just type "Logarithmic" and you'll get several examples:
[image]

Comment: Would be useful! I just googled "lightningcharts log plot" to see what options were available. I haven't used LC yet.

Comment: Please check my updated answer above... let us know LightningChart team can help more.

Comment: Wow, very nice!